# Correct syntax for calling a group of objects in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list with 1000 items in it but only want to call a certain range of them.

```
class myClass():

    def event(self):
        #do stuff


my_list = [myClass(i) for i in range(1000)]

#incorrect part:
my_list[0 - 10].event()
```

Meaning that I am trying to call "event" for only the first 9 objects. What would be the correct way to write this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
for obj in my_list[:9]:
    obj.event()
```

Note since you just want the first 9 objects to be called, you need to use indexes 0-8 i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Answer (score 3):

```
[x.event() for x in my_list[:9]]
```

or

```
list(map(lambda x: x.event(), my_list[:9]))
```

or, as @khredos suggests,

```
for obj in my_list[:9]:
    obj.event()
```

If `myClass.event()` does return something (and you want to keep the result), the first is the most pythonic. If, on the other hand, `myClass.event()` involves side effects (and you do not want to keep the result, of course), go for the the third approach.